# Oracle SQL to display results from dividing one variable with another

Tags: oracle, variables, division

I need to calculate the YTD **weekly** average for the GROSS_AMOUNT

In the below script, the first part of the code gets the number of weeks. The second part of the code gets the YTD sum for that same time period

How do I write the SQL **so I can retrieve the actual value of YtdTotal/TotalWeeks**?

SELECT YtdTotal/TotalWeeks FROM DUAL;  does not work

```
-- STORES NUMBER OF WEEKS SINCE BEGINING OF YEAR INTO THE VARIABLE, TotalWeeks
DECLARE
    TotalWeeks NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'WW')) - to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'year'),'WW'))
    INTO TotalWeeks
    FROM DUAL
    -- (retrieves number of weeks since beginning of year)
END

-- STORES THE SUM OF GROSS)AMOUNT FOR THE WEEKS CALCULATED ABOVE - INTO THE 
DECLARE
    VARIABLE, YtdTotal
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(GROSS_AMOUNT) 
    INTO YtdTotal
    FROM PARENTS
    WHERE process_date BETWEEN
    (next_day(TRUNC(sysdate, 'year'),'SUN'))
    AND
    (next_day(TRUNC(sysdate),'SAT')-7);
END;
```

Comment: Why are you applying to_date to sysdate?  to_date converts a _string_ to a DATE (data type) , and sysdate _is_ a DATE.  Also your code will be mucn easier for us to read if instead of a screen shot, you actually copy and paste the text, formatting the pasted text as "code".  Also, it will help if you provide the DDL for the tables and INSERTs to create representative data.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have corrected the to_date issue and have replaced the screenshot with the code format.

All I really need to know is the right syntax for retrieving the value of   YtdTotal DIVIDE BY TotalWeeks. These are the variables that I am passing the calculations to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use two separate anonymous PL/SQL blocks - combine them into one!

If you want to return the result, then - instead of an anonymous PL/SQL block - create a **function**.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test
  return NUMBER
IS
   totalweeks  NUMBER;
   ytdtotal    NUMBER;
   result      NUMBER;
BEGIN
   -- STORES NUMBER OF WEEKS SINCE BEGINING OF YEAR INTO THE VARIABLE, TotalWeeks
   SELECT   TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'WW'))
          - TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'year'), 'WW'))
     INTO totalweeks
     FROM DUAL;

   -- (retrieves number of weeks since beginning of year)

   -- STORES THE SUM OF GROSS)AMOUNT FOR THE WEEKS CALCULATED ABOVE - INTO THE
   SELECT SUM (gross_amount)
     INTO ytdtotal
     FROM parents
    WHERE process_date BETWEEN (NEXT_DAY (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'year'), 'SUN'))
                           AND (NEXT_DAY (TRUNC (SYSDATE), 'SAT') - 7);

   -- the final result
   result := ytdtogal / totalweeks;
   RETURN result;
END;
/
```

Use it as

```
select f_test from dual;
```

Comment: The query executed successfully, thank you. But I'm not sure how to retrieve the actual value from the "result" variable. I tried SELECT RESULT FROM DUAL, and that did not work

Comment: It would be a function, then. I edited the answer, have a look.